# What is the explanation for the outcome of this C language code?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

This is a problem on my Computer Science final study guide. The correct answer is x[2] = 7 and x[4] = 4. When I tried interpreting the code it seemed like the value of x[2] wasn't even changed by the sort function. But it was! Could someone explain why x[2] = 7 and x[4] = 4? Thank you!

```
#include<stdio.h>

 #define SIZE 10

 void sort(int[], int);

 int main()
 {
   int x[SIZE] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0};
   sort(x, -1);
   printf("x[2] = %d\n", x[2]);
   sort(x, 1);

   printf("x[4] = %d\n", x[4]);
   return(0);
 }

 void sort(int x[], int dir)
 {
   int i;
   int j;
   int temp;

   for(i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
     for(j = SIZE - 1; j >= i; j--)
     {
       if(dir == -1 && x[j] > x[j - 1] || dir == 1 && x[j] < x[j - 1])
       {
         temp = x[j - 1];
         x[j - 1] = x[j];
         x[j] = temp;
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` function is a bubblesort variant.  If `dir` is -1, it sorts the array in descending order.  If `dir` is 1, it sorts the array in ascending order.

After the first sort, the array will be in descending order:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

So `x[2]` will be 7.

After the second sort, the arry will be in ascending order:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

So `x[4]` will be 4.

Answer (score 0):

The code goes along these lines:

```
from left to right in the array
  from right to left in the array, as long as you hit the upcoming count
     if the current left is bigger than it's lower predecessor
        swap 'em
```

Its a kind of an exchange sort algorithm.
X[2] is touched by the inner loop possibly two times

- first since j >= i
- secondly in the comparision with the predecessor